# angular editable control multi language component or directive

Tags: angular, components, directive, angular5

What is the best way to create a control to define the value of a field in several languages.
Should I use the directives or components.
I would like that when I am logged in as admin, when clicking on a field, all the languages ​​are displayed with the possibility to modify the values.

thank you in advance

Comment: set i18n, there is official Docs https://angular.io/guide/i18n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you don't need to create a component or anything for it.

One of the ways you do translations in angular is using [ngx-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core)

**Usage** is very simple: [image]

Have a look at this

Comment: It seems pretty thank you. Do you use it ? I have used i118 from angular but could not load all translation on demand because need deployment

Comment: I have used it but sorry I didn't deploy it

Comment: thank you @Muhammad
Do you if it's support by material angular